# Flask SQLaclemy AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'all'

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to take request and use that variable and then use that variable in a SELECT * FROM (VARIABLE) for my database,

It works in the python command line but not in my file to render template.

Here is my code sorry im new to this.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root:@localhost/bustedin2'
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Offender2(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    Name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False, nullable=False)
    DOB = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False, nullable=False)
    Sex = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False, nullable=False)
    Race = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False, nullable=False)
    Charge = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False, nullable=False)
    ChargeLevel = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False, nullable=False)
    ArrestDate = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False, nullable=False)
    City = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False, nullable=False)
    State = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False, nullable=False)
    BookingNumber = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False, nullable=False)
    ArrestDate = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False, nullable=False)
    AddedToDataBaseDate = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False, nullable=False)


# notice that all models inherit from SQLAlchemy's db.Model

# Make the WSGI interface available at the top level so wfastcgi can get it.
wsgi_app = app.wsgi_app


@app.route('/')
def show_all():
    return render_template('ShowAll.html', offenders=Offender2.query.all())


@app.route("/Details/<int:id>")
def show_one(id):
    found_Offender = Offender2.query.get(id)
    return render_template('details.html', offender=found_Offender)


# @app.route('/Details/Multi/<int:BookingNumber>')
# def get_booking():
# BookingNumber = request.args.get('BookingNumber')
# Found_Booking = Offender2.query.filter(Offender2.BookingNumber == "BookingNumber")
# return render_template('ShowMultible.html', offenders = Found_Booking)

@app.route('/Details/Multi/<int:BookingNumber>')
def Show_Multi(BookingNumber):
    Found_Booking = Offender2.query.get("BookingNumber").all()
    return render_template('ShowMultible.html', offenders=Found_Booking)
```

This is the area where im having issues..

```
 @app.route('/Details/Multi/<int:BookingNumber>')
    def Show_Multi(BookingNumber):
        Found_Booking = Offender2.query.get("BookingNumber").all()
        return render_template('ShowMultible.html', offenders=Found_Booking)
```

Comment: Can you modify your question to include the actual traceback you are getting. Your title indicates that the error is coming from the show_all route, but you mention the problem is in the Show_Multi route.

Comment: Okay so i tried all different ways so the error came from   Found_Booking = Offender2.query.get("BookingNumber").all()

Comment: im just not getting the data to the template like the (id) just like the show_one(id): method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@app.route('/Details/Multi/<int:BookingNumber>')
def Show_Multi(BookingNumber):
    Found_Booking = Offender2.query.get("BookingNumber").all()
    return render_template('ShowMultible.html', offenders=Found_Booking)
```

In this section of code, you're performing a query for an Offender2 entry with primary key equal to the string "BookingNumber" (not the variable). Additionally, if you're using `get` this returns the object, so you don't need to call `all()`. Try changing your code to:

```
Found_Booking = Offender2.query.get(BookingNumber)
```

**Edit:**

Just realised BookingNumber isn't your primary key, so this won't work. You need to get results by filtering on the BookingNumber field.

```
Found_Booking = Offender2.query.filter_by(BookingNumber=BookingNumber).all()
```

Also, your BookingNumber in the database is stored as a string so you should change your route definition from int:

```
@app.route('/Details/Multi/<BookingNumber>')
```

Comment: Now I get this  Found_Booking = Offender2.query.all("BookingNumber")
TypeError: all() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: You don't need to call all(), try changing this to get() as suggested. And you are still passing a string instead of a variable.

Comment: Okay sorry change it to Offender2.query.get(BookingNumber) and I get a blank template no data..    this is what im using in the template to test the data being passed...            {{ offenders.Name }}

Comment: Sorry, just realised that BookingNumber isn't your primary key in the database table. Have edited my answer with more information.

Comment: Note if you only want one result you can use .first() instead of .all().

Comment: Thanks man I realized that because i had that code commented out and was like why is it saying id.

Comment: Whats the best way to learn? lol i'm trying to learn by building random things,

Comment: That's often the best way! Also recommend this tutorial: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world